# Why is there a whole lotta shakin' goin' on in Alderaan?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So, it was my understanding that within the Star Wars timeline, we're still many centuries away from this:

So then why, as I adventure around Alderaan, do I periodically hear loud rumbling noises, accompanied by my entire screen shaking.

Is there some kind of ongoing Seismic Event?

Comment: (As a side note, the inclusion of the Destruction of Alderaan clip is to rule it out as a snarky comment-answer. It's already what I was told when I asked my guild this question.)

Comment: The Jedi Knight story line involves a doomsday weapon that attacks individual targets anywhere, anytime. Could it be due to that weapon firing?

Comment: This is a multiplayer game? I... but I thought... bioware and RPGs... O.o

Comment: Maybe it's due to the civil war for the throne happening between House Organa and the House Thul exiles. Perhaps you got a bit close to the boom-booms?

Comment: Does it happen in one specific are or anywhere you go? Does it happen in cities too?

Comment: I've had it happen everywhere, from the Spaceport to Fort Ulgo and back.

Comment: Maybe it is just an earthquake IRL? :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It's war. More specifically, cannon fire.

From the codex entry on Alderaan:

> Alderaan is a mountainous world of lush forests and grasslands, ruled by an assembly of noble houses and an enlightened and advanced citizenry. A founding member of the Republic, Alderaan has been traditionally admired for its wealth, its art and its thinkers, while the deadly intrigues and politics of the nobility have been downplayed.
>
> Recently, those intrigues erupted into civil war, and Alderaan--now officially withdrawn from the Republic--sees conflict it hasn't known in ages. The Republic is backing House Organa's quest for the crown, whereas the Empire backs the former House Thul exiles. **Palaces and fields have become pockmarked by cannon fire, and house armies clash on the battlefield**.

Source: http://www.torhead.com/codex/1afjgDN

Another likely candidate for planet-shaking is the [planetary defense cannon](http://swtor.wikia.com/wiki/Planetary_Defense) fought over in the Alderaan Warzone (PvP).

[image]

Comment: Cannons are capable of causing the entire planet to shake? Seems a bit much.

Comment: No, and I doubt they do. But large artillery can make it seem like the ground is shaking. And game developers love to exaggerate.

Comment: [Hammer Station](http://www.torhead.com/codex/12imIJQ) could definitely make a planet shake too (it shoots Asteroids accelerated to near lightspeed [astrophysics has no place in the Star Wars universe]), although it's not suggested in the story that Alderaan was one of it's targets.